# NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 102: No query results for model [App\....]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I tried to edit/update my data in database. But always get this error.

```
NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 102: No query results for model [App\Produk]
```

Here's the function in `controller`:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $data = Produk::findOrFail($id);
    return view('pages.admin.edit')->with('data',$data);
}
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $data = Produk::findOrFail($id);
    $data->update($request->all());
    return redirect('pages.admin.lihat');
}
```

And here's my `edit.blade.php` form:

```
    {!! Form::model($data,['method'=>'PATCH','url' => 'admin/update']) !!}

<div class="contact-form">
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Nama Produk') !!}
    {!! Form::text('nama', null, 
        array('required', 
              'class'=>'form-control', 
              'placeholder'=>'Nama Produk')) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Jumlah Produk') !!}
    {!! Form::number('jumlah', null, 
        array('required', 
              'class'=>'form-control', 
              'placeholder'=>'Jumlah Produk')) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Harga') !!}
    {!! Form::text('harga', null, 
        array('required', 
              'class'=>'form-control', 
              'placeholder'=>'Harga')) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Gambar') !!}
    {!! Form::text('images', null, 
        array('required', 
              'class'=>'form-control', 
              'placeholder'=>'Gambar')) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Edit', 
      array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}
</div>

</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I use this in my `routes` (the first one is for the store function so nothing to do with this update):

```
Route::post('admin/success','ProdukController@simpan');

Route::resource('admin','ProdukController');
```

And the `Produk` Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produk extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =[

        'nama',
        'jumlah',
        'harga',
        'images'

    ];
}
```

Comment: `Produk::findOrFail($id);` will throw an exception if the Model is not found. Use `Produk::where('id', $id)->first();` instead;  It returns an empty result (instead of throwing an exception) if no Model with the corresponding `id` is found.

Comment: I changed it to `$data = Produk::where('id', $id)->first();` but now got FatalError `Call to a member function update() on null` @Adrenaxus

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are trying to update a nonexistent `Produk` by passing an `id` that has no corresponding Model. You need to check before updating. E.g. `if (!$data->isEmpty()) { $data->update($request->all()); }`

Comment: @Adrenaxus That's the problem. The `update` function doesn't get the id that requested. But my `edit` function is working well and it does get the data with that `id` from database into the edit form.

Comment: Please show us your `edit()` function in your controller and the Model for `Produk`.

Comment: @Adrenaxus Here's the edit function: `public function edit($id)
 {
  $data = Produk::findOrFail($id);
  return view('pages.admin.edit')->with('data',$data);
 }`

And the Model:
`<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produk extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =[
 
  'nama',
  'jumlah',
  'harga',
  'images'
 
 ];
}`

Comment: @Adrenaxus updated in the question

Comment: Can you show us what your URL looks like when updating?

Comment: @Adrenaxus I tried to change the url in `edit.blade` to this `'url' => 'admin/'.$data->id.'/update'`. It does get the `id` and the URL in the browser is `http://localhost/laravel/admin/2/update` but I got the `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php` now

Comment: You are using [RESTful resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers). Your update URL should be `/admin/{produk_id}` instead of `/admin/{produk_id}/update`. If you show us your update view we can narrow down the error even further.

Comment: the update.blade.php only show the message that the update is success. the function in the controller for update is now this 
`public function update($id, Request $request)
 { 
  $data = Produk::where('id', $id)->first();
  $data->update($request->all());
  return view('pages.admin.update');
 }`

Answer (score 0):

that happens cause data with that id doesn't exits `$data = Produk::findOrFail($id)` . you can use `Produk::find($id);`or `data = Produk::where('id', $id)->first();` (it won't throw an error)

read more at [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates)

Comment: Now I got this `FatalErrorException in ProdukController.php line 40: Call to a member function update() on null`

Comment: are you sure that data with that id exists in database?

Comment: When I get the data with the same `id` to the edit form, it does works. But keep getting errors when I try to update it. So I'm sure the `id` is exist in database.

Comment: its strange) cause all these errors say that data doesn't exist. please, post more code here, to make it more clear. try to fill in id manually, for example `Produk::find(1);`  `Produk::find(2);` .... fill in id which exists in db for sure. just check if it works

Comment: Is the URL in my `edit.blade.php` seems correct? Because when I tried to change it to `'url' => 'admin/'.$data->id.'/update'` I got `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161` but it still get the 'id'

Comment: did you try `dd($data)` or `var_dump($data)` ? is it empty? post your routes.php

Comment: where I have to put that? all routes that used for this controller are in the question above

Comment: sorry, i didn't look attentively. try to comment this `Route::resource('admin','ProdukController');` and make all these routes manually . something like this `Route::get('/admin/update/{$id}');` see if it works

Comment: Still got `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php`. And now the edit function get this error too when I change the route manually.

Comment: something wrong with routes. do you use any prefix? comment all routes which relates to `admin` leave only, for example `Route::get('/admin/update/{$id}');` type it manually in browser query string, for example `localhost:8000/admin/update/1` or any other id which exists.

Comment: still the same NotFoundHttpException

Comment: try these commands `php artisan cache:clear` , `php artisan view:clear` , `composer dump-autoload` , also restart your server. if you want, upload your project to github(if its not a private project) or other public repository, so i can run it locally, if you wish ofcourse ))

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the id to the url on form opening try to change it as follow:

```
{!! Form::model($data,['method'=>'PATCH','route' => ['admin.update', $data->id] ]) !!}
```